# Inner class with upper bound

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.9

I'd like to create a generic class with type parameter `T` which then creates instances of an inner class wrapping values of type `T`. I thought that if I used upper bound to tell that `T` must be subtype of eg. `String`, I'll be able to create instances of the inner class initialized with a `String`.

```
class Test[T <: String] {

    private class TestEntry(val value: T)

    def init: Unit = {
        new TestEntry("")
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("")
 required: T
               new TestEntry("")
                         ^
```

Actually, for my purpose, it would do to omit the upper bound and call `new TestEntry(null)`, but the compiler does not even accept `null`.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Let me rephrase my example, I need something like this: I should be able to test an abstract luxury car service with any specific car without the need to re-implement the testing method. So both the abstract class (or trait) and the methods should work on subclasses of luxury cars.

```
class Car
class LuxuryCar extends Car
class Mercedes extends LuxuryCar
class Ferrari extends LuxuryCar

trait LuxuryCarService[CarType <: LuxuryCar] {

    def testWithCar(car: CarType): Unit = {}

    def testWithARandomLuxuryCar: Unit = test(new Mercedes)

    def testWithNoCar: Unit = test(null)
}

trait MercedesCarService extends LuxuryCarService[Mercedes]
```

Comment: Supposing that the test method you call is testWithCar, I don't see why you expect a Mercedes should be accepted by a LuxuryCarService[Ferrari] in testWithARandomLuxuryCar, exact same problem as in @Rex Kerr's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've told it that `T` is a subclass of `String`.  You then turn around and try to assign a string to it!  That isn't going to work, any more than this will:

```
class Car {}
class Mercedes extends Car {}         // Mercedes <: Car (T could be Mercedes)
def serviceLuxuryCar(m: Mercedes) {}  // This is like your TestEntry
serviceLuxuryCar(new Car)             // This won't work, it's not a Mercedes!
```

I'm not sure what you actually mean for the code to do, but what you wrote should not (and does not, as you've found out) work.

Comment: Thanks, I added a more specific example (which also doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix it).

Answer (score 2):

Let go of the type parameter. Declare stuff as `LuxuryCar` instead of `CarType`. Why do you think you need a type parameter here?

Answer (score 0):

> I should be able to test an abstract luxury car service with any specific car without the need to re-implement the testing method.

Then that's what the type should say:

```
def testWithCar(car: Car): Unit = {} // or LuxuryCar if you meant "with any specific luxury car"
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are I'm missing something, but... why use a generic here at all?
In other words, why not

`trait LuxuryCarService[LuxuryCar]`